# Overwrite and restore environment variables in bash with environment modules

Tags: bash, environment-modules

An environment variable that is overwritten in an environment module with the `setenv` command is unset when unloading the module. In the documentation [it is stated that environment variables can be restored](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulefile.html#mfcmd-setenv), but no method is provided.

I tried using conditional execution, but the following module (`~/privatemodules/test`) fails to restore an environment variable `FOO`.

```
#%Module########################################################################
##
## test modulefile
##
  proc ModulesHelp { } {
  puts stderr "This module modifies an environment variable FOO."
}

module-whatis "Modify environment varible FOO"

if { [module-info mode load] } {
  setenv ORIGINAL_FOO $::env(FOO)
  setenv FOO "123"
} elseif { [module-info mode unload] } {
  setenv FOO $::env(ORIGINAL_FOO)
  unsetenv ORIGINAL_FOO
}
```

For instance I get:

```sh
$ export FOO=bar
$ module load use.own && module load test
$ echo $FOO
123
$ module unload test
$ echo $FOO

$
```

Is there a method to restore the original value of `FOO`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is found in the documentation. The [`unsetenv`](https://modules.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modulefile.html#mfcmd-unsetenv) takes an extra parameter to set the environment variable to a new value. So the module file should be:

```
#%Module########################################################################
##
## test modulefile
##
  proc ModulesHelp { } {
  puts stderr "This module modifies an environment variable FOO."
}

module-whatis "Modify environment varible FOO"

if { [module-info mode load] } {
  setenv ORIGINAL_FOO $::env(FOO)
  setenv FOO "123"
} elseif { [module-info mode unload] } {
  unsetenv FOO $::env(ORIGINAL_FOO)
}
```

This changes in version 5.